# What is the special operator "~" in R?

Tags: r, model, operator-keyword, random-forest, tilde

I am a beginner in R. I am currently using random forest to do some prediction. When I read the document, it has following command lines:

iris_rf <- randomForest(Species~.,data=trainData,ntree=100,proximity=TRUE)  ///// build random forest

It looks like the 'Species' is the input data set, but I don't understand, what does the "Species~." mean, particularly what is the meaning of the operator '~.'
    I have never seen such kind of operator before.

Comment: Since you are a begginer in R, I recommend you take a look to [The Quick-R tutorial](http://statmethods.net)

Answer (score 4):

[Sorry all I should have searched that the OP's question was a duplicate]

This is the syntax R uses for ***formulas***.

All it means is that *dependent variable* ***~ ('depends on')*** *independent variables*.

As for 'DepVar ~ .' , we use '.' instead of *independent variables* to signify 'all other variables in the dataset'.